# Is there a way to make a docker container recognize renewed certificates and restart its process?

Tags: docker, lets-encrypt, certbot

I'm still in the process of learning to use Docker, but I think I've managed to build a decent image that runs certbot and gets my various websites' ssl certificates. This image does the initial certbot request if it doesn't see any certificates, then starts up crond with a single job that runs the renewal command.

The certificates themselves are chucked into a named volume mapped to /etc/letsencrypt.

I had intended to attach this volume to the other containers that need access to the certificates. However, it occurs to me that when the renewal goes through, new certificate files will show up available to those containers, but the apps themselves won't restart or notice them.

Is there a reasonable way to accomplish this? At first I thought this might be a way to manage certs without having to have scripts ssh/scp all over the place, but I can't think of a way to make the web apps recognize that the certs have been renewed accept to do that. Is there a trick or strategy that can make this work, or is the idea just a dead end?

Answer (score 1):

A docker container can control other docker containers... it can start/restart/stop containers and other commands as you would on the command line.

It's necessary to mount the `/var/run/docker.sock` into the container for this to be possible, and there are security concerns for this.

Then the (cron) job that renews certificates can be modified to restart any containers that make use of a shared certificates volume, with something like:

```
--renew-hook "/usr/bin/curl --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock -X POST http:/v1.24/containers/gitea/restart"
```

Keep in mind that Docker itself has other recommendations for how to do certificates using the `docker secret` functionality (only available in swarm mode).